# Form Validaton Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var val_regex = \d{3}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
function validate(form){
    var valOne = form.valone.value;
    var valTwo = form.valtwo.value;
    var valThree = form.valthree.value;


     if (!val_regex.test(valOne)) || (!val_regex.test(valTwo)) ||(!val_regex.test(valThree)){
        $("#val-error").html("Error with inputted value");
        $('#val-error').fadeIn(200).delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
        return false;
     }
     return true;
    }
}
```

My regex expression here doesn't seem to be working. Can you see what the problem is?

Regex expression - what I want - any number between 0 and 999 (inclusive) - there is a maximum of 2 decimal places allowed. Am I writing the regex expression the wrong way or is my javascript wrong?

Comment: 2 decimal points? string like 1.2.3 should pass?

Comment: Sorry I meant 1.23 or 232.49 would pass but not 12.1.2

Comment: Ha ... I'm an idiot. My solution was for PHP, not JavaScript. Back to bed for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't match single, or double digit numbers.

Try this:

```
var val_regex = /^(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9]))(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;
```

Comment: Can you provide some input/output so we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: I ran this through the firebug console for several inputs, it's working now (after my edit).  The problem before was that the regex wasn't matching the entire string, just a part of it (hence the ^ at the beginning now)

Comment: Does my JavaScript code look wrong - because it goes into the if statement/I get an error statement everytime.

Comment: why yes, your parentheses are unbalanced in your if statement :-)

Comment: For something like this: var statValOne = form.statone.value;  Statone refers to the name of a form element or does it refer to the id of a form element?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21524/discussion-between-will-c-and-josebazbaz)

Comment: This ended up working - I realized I was linking to the wrong input from the html - I changed that and it worked problem-free. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val_regex = /^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
```

Explanation:

```
\d{1,3}
```

Allow 1-3 digits.

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Allow 1-3 digits and, optionally, allow a period and 1-2 more digits.

```
^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

All of the above, but allow nothing else before or after it.  Make sure you `.trim()` your inputs to eliminate any whitespace before and after.

This will allow "0" - "999".  It will also allow "0.0", "0.00" and "999.99" but not "0." (must have at least digit after the decimal place).